# What is diplomatic crisis in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please explain what is diplomatic crisis in the below paragraph.

The referendum is crucial for Mr. Erdogan’s ambitious plans to overhaul Turkey’s political system. If he gets the reforms approved by a majority of voters, Turkey would move towards a presidential system. He would then handpick his own cabinet and his Justice and Development Party’s MPs and gain at least two five-year terms uncontested. It is therefore unsurprising that Mr. Erdogan is turning the **diplomatic crisis** into a political battle to appeal to nationalist sections of the electorate. But the crisis could have undesirable outcomes. European leaders fear that Mr. Erdogan’s outreach could help the anti-Muslim far-right parties in the continent. In the Netherlands, which went to the polls on Wednesday, the far-right candidate, Geert Wilders, has already questioned the “loyalty” of Dutch Muslims of Turkish origin and called for a tough response to Ankara.

Comment: it means the pate and olives have run  out

Answer (score 2):

Diplomatic crisis just like crisis itself stands for problems, difficulties and obstacles.

In this context it means current political situation in the World (Turkish-Russian crisis, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In the Netherlands, which went to the polls on Wednesday, the far-right candidate, Geert Wilders, has already questioned the “loyalty” of Dutch Muslims of Turkish origin and called for a tough response to Ankara

This is the diplomatic crisis.